# How to center input tag in a table cell?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on an Angular 2 CLI project. But while designing my pages I had this issue where I could not center my inputs. Weirdly, I can center my button below my input tags, but I don't know why my inputs are not centered. I am already using the code below in my CSS;

```
text-align: center; 
vertical-align: middle;
```

**This is how my page looks like;**

[image]

**This is my HTML code**

```
<div class="card bg-light" >
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="card-table table table-hover" style="margin: auto;">
      <thead style="background-color: #527678; color: aliceblue;">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Ingredients</th>
          <th scope="col">Cup(Bardak)</th>
          <th scope="col">Grams</th>
          <th scope="col">Calories</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>
            <input type="email" id="form3Example3" class="form-control" style="width: 60%;" />
          </td>
          <td>           
              <input type="email" id="form3Example3" class="form-control" />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="email" id="form3Example3" class="form-control" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="email" id="form3Example3" class="form-control" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-floating" >
              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
          
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is my CSS code**

```
.card {
    margin: 0 auto; /* Added */
    float: none; /* Added */
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* Added */
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 70%;
}

.table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
    background-color: #d1dedf;
  }

.btn-primary {
    background-color: #527678 !important;
    border-color: #476668; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}

input{
    width: 30%;
}

.btn-primary:hover,.btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:focus,  .btn-primary:active:hover {
    background-color: #476668 !important;
}

.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #527678;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(71, 102, 104, 0.6);
  }
td,th {
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I would really appreciate the help :)

Comment: if the input is displayed as block, you can margin auto, if its displayed inline, then align text center in <td> will be ok

Comment: @AhmadAlaa thanks a lot, i added margin auto to my input tag and it worked. :))

Comment: @AhmadAlaa you should answer my question so i can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the input is displayed as block, you can margin auto

```
input { margin: auto; }
```

if its displayed inline, then align text center to "td" will be OK

```
td { text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

add display:block; and margin:0 auto; to the input field